# Reading a certain bit from a u32int

Tags: c++, int

I input a value containing an unsigned 32-bit int and I want to read bit number 19. How can I do that?

This is the input I want to read the bit from:

```
uint32 Input = u32AHI_DioReadInput();
int x = ???
```

I tried using `Input(19)` and `input[19]` but i didn't work cause the first one is a function and the second is considered as if it is an array. I know that I should and some of the bits and shift them but I just don't know how can I do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you need to read a single bit `n`, shift the number right by `n` positions, and cut out all bits except the last one, like this:

```
int x = (Input >> n) & 1;
```

The `>> n` shifts the content by `n` bits to the right; the `& 1` does a bitwise "AND" with one (its binary representation has only the lowest bit set to one, all other bits contain zeros);